# Redirection by engineer to other site?

Tags: discussion

[Problem testing an ADC with a DAC and voltage divider](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101769/problem-testing-an-adc-with-a-dac-and-voltage-divider)

How do folks feel about this?  Looks like a TI engineer reposting on behalf of a SE poster on the TI site.  Might be a great way to help the OP, but feels sorta funny to me.

Comment: [StackExchange policy on srapers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Reported to SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) and left comment for user as this seems to have good intent.

You are allowed to copy content with attribution, this is lacking it and seems to clearly be attempting to drag users to their site for discussion of a question on our site.